# How to put an iterator into a thread in python, and get return value as next cannot be used in thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am now building two components, a receiver (receiver.py) and a scraper (a software). The scraper would get data from database and send to a receiver through a socket. There is a machine learning model in the receiver, receive collected data and return an order to determine what kind of data should collect next. The socket in receiver would listen until it receives an order "terminate". In order to return the collected data and keep the socket open at the same time, I use "yield" and change the socket into a generator. And get data with next()

```
class receiver:
     def __init__(self, orders):
          self.orders = orders #orders is a list
     def start(self):
          while True:
               client_socket.send(orders)
               collected_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
               yield collected_data
     def add_order(self, new_orders):
          self.orders.append(new_orders)

r = receiver("search field 1") #ask the scraper to search field 1
r_generator = r.start()
field1_data = next(r_generator)
r.add_order("search field 2")
field2_data = next(r_generator)
```

The code run correctly when I run receiver and the scraper seperately. The collected data would send from scraper to the receiver through socket, and assign to variables. I can add new order to let the scraper search new data (connection of receiver and scraper is closed, but the socket in receiver is still listening)

Now I need to put them together into one python file, and starting the scraper with python command:

```
subprocess.check_output('cmd run scaper')
```

I need to run them simultaneously, hence I use thread

```
r_generator = r.start
t1 = Thread(target = next, args=(r_generator)).start()
t2 = Thread(target = subprocess.check_output('cmd run scaper')).start()
```

But I can no longer do add_order or assigning the collected data to variable as

```
field1_data = next(r_generator)
field1_data = next(t1)
```

are not workable, and

```
t1 = Thread(target = r_generator).start()
r.add_order("search field 2")
t1.join()
```

The "search field 2" order would add directly after the thread start, but what I want is get field 1 data first then to decide if doing another search or what field should be searched.

Comment: Your code examples are not complete enough. Everything you posted looks correct. The error must be in something you left out from the question.

Comment: @exhuma I may not state clearly. the r_generator in the thread t1 should be = r.start, but nothing would happen with t1.start(), the program end directly when t2 complete and the software cannot connect to the socket in receiver. And if using r_generator = r.start(), error raise: 'generator' object is not callable.

Comment: Can you update the question with those details please? This will make it easier to follow for anybody else coming across this question.

Comment: @exhuma I have update more detail